# How to use a function as a row number in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I want to print the value contained in D7 (Row 7, Column D) into another cell.

I would use `=D7`.

Great.

But what if I have a function that returns a number, like [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378), and I want to use that returned number as the row number in my previous example?

I don't know how to do that and where to find that information.

Something like: `=D{MATCH("ETH",A:A,1)}`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT("D" & MATCH(...))
```

or

```
=INDEX(D1:D, MATCH(...), 1)
```

The latter is likely to be faster, the former is a more general solution.